# array to string when parse template

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing, templates

I have 2 files, call index.php and home.html.

this is index.php contents:

```
$language = [
    'say' => 'Good Bye.',
];

function template($html)
{
    global $tmpl;
    global $language;

    $tmpl['static'] = 'Example';

    $tmpl['dynamic'] = $language;

    $file = sprintf('%s.html', $html);
    $f_skin = fopen($file, 'r');
    $skin = @fread($f_skin, filesize($file));
    fclose($f_skin);
    return preg_replace_callback(
            '/{\$([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)}/',
        function($matches) {
                global $tmpl; return (isset($tmpl[$matches[1]])?$tmpl[$matches[1]]:"");
            }, $skin
    );
}

echo template('home');
```

and this is home.html contents:

```
<div class="tag">

{$static}

</div>
```

when i use {$static} everything working fine, but, when i use this, i get an error:

```
{$dynamic['say']} 
//or
 {$dynamic->say}
```

i need something like this to get value from array.

Comment: Please refer this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922771/simple-php-template-parsing]

Comment: I saw it and it is different from my question.thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `$skin`?

Comment: when i enter : {$dynamic['say']}  , the output will be:  {$dynamic['say']}